# Generate one random string of characters, that refreshes once every 24 hours?

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am trying to work out a way in which I can generate a random string made up of letters and numbers, that regenerates a new string every 24 hours, and will not change on page refresh etc.

I currently have the below code, which works in generating a random code, but I'm not sure how to go about tweaking it to meet my needs.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function couponfunction() {
        echo generateRandomString();
    }

add_shortcode( 'coupon', 'couponfunction');
```

Is this something that is possible just through PHP functions? Or will I need to look at setting up a Cron job?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to look into what it means to _seed_ a random number generator. As long as you use the same seed value, every call will give you the _same_ random result. So you don’t actually have to store this anywhere or use a cron, you can calculate it on-the-fly whenever you need it - just provide a seed that stays the same for the whole day. (Could be for example the current date as a number, in `YYYYMMDD` format.)

Comment: To get a number that changes once per 24-hour period: `(int) (time() / 86400)`. You can hash it, or use it as the seed for an RNG, as suggested by misorude.